# MYSQL if statement question

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```
Is there any way to get the if statement to evaluate a query?

SELECT if(5>0,'EQ_Type','*') FROM EQUIPMENT;

Resulting in:
+-----------------------+
| IF(5>0,'EQ_Type','*') |
+-----------------------+
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
| EQ_Type               |
+-----------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)




I would like the above statement to be equivalent to the following:

SELECT 'EQ_Type' FROM EQUIPMENT;

And produce:
+--------------+
| EQ_Type      |
+--------------+
| ENGINE       |
| ENGINE       |
| ENGINE       |
| TRAILER      |
| TRAILER      |
| TRAILER      |
| WATER TENDER |
| WATER TENDER |
| WATER TENDER |
+--------------+


Thanks for any help
```

Comment: Wont 5>0 always result in 'true', hence EQ_Type? I dont know MySql very well so I might be misreading that. Was this just a contrived example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes.

```
SELECT if(5>0,EQ_Type,'*') FROM EQUIPMENT;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I am a novice so I figured it would be something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using ANSI notation - [CASE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) in this case - rather than MySQL specific syntax:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 5 > 0 THEN t.eq_type ELSE '*' END
  FROM EQUIPMENT t
```

Reason being, if you changed databases - this statement wouldn't need to be changed to work on Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.