# Count rows in one table within a IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, count

Is it possible to check if num rows in a table is 0 then perform an insert, all in ONE sql statement?

Here's my query that I tried but it says I have a syntax error:

```
$query = 
    "IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM votes WHERE userid = $userid AND itemid = $itemid AND itemtype=1) = 0
        INSERT INTO votes (itemtype, itemid, userid) VALUES (1, $itemid, $userid) 
        SELECT 1 AS result
    ELSE
        SELECT 0 AS result
    END IF";
```

I know the SELECT COUNT bit works successfully on its own.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898472/mysql-if-statement-question

Comment: I'm not aware of any SQL DB that supports that specific syntax, all on the SQL side. Set a variable in PHP to the result of your query and make the if/else check be in PHP code, and then make the appropriate secondary call, if necessary. Another option is to use case statements in you query to determine the insert value.

Comment: @JeffHines I don't think that helps as I need to do an INSERT within the if statement

Comment: @ahillman3 The issue is I want to make sure 2 votes can't be cast on the same item, so I don't want any gap between the checking they haven't already voted and the voting

Comment: In that case, go with the suggestion by @cwallenpoole. You'll just need to eat any exceptions as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO IDEA if this is the best way of solving this, but it will work. Basically, it simply causes an error if the condition is false, and so it prevents insert:

```sql
-- make itemtype not nullable then simply insert
INSERT INTO votes SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN 
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) 
         FROM votes 
         WHERE userid = $userid AND itemid = $itemid AND itemtype=1) = 0 THEN 1
      ELSE NULL
    END CASE,
    $itemid, $userid;
```

Comment: Ah! This method will not work as SQL doesn't let you INSERT INTO a table that you are also SELECTING from later on in the query... any advice? EDIT: Managed it with the ugly work around of giving the SELECT statement an ID (AS x).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to MySQL to test this right now, but would this work?

```
INSERT INTO votes (itemtype, itemid, userid)
(SELECT  1,$itemid, $userid 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM votes 
   WHERE itemtype=1 
   AND itemid=$itemid
   AND userid=$userid))
```